# Как вместо Content в Label выводить Image

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения, list, label

Делаю игру, столкнулся с таким вопросом вообще возможно ли это:
хочу реализовать список List, в котором будут элементы Label; 
Пример кода в C#;

```
List Cards = new Cards(){label1,label2...};
```

XML WPF:

```
<Label x:Name="Label1" />
<Label x:Name="Label2" />
```

И мне нужно привязать переменную Label1 к картинке ImageSource="C:\...."

Вот встал вопрос: возможно ли вообще это реализовать?

Comment: Я вам советую понять все с самого начала, узнайте что такое привязки, как с ними работать, тогда у вас подобных вопросов не будет. В двух словах: Использовать контролы в коде - ЗЛО! Создайте отдельный класс, который будет содержать в себе публичные свойства, необходимые для привязки (путь до картинки например), дальше сделайте коллекцию этих классов, тоже как публичное свойство. Ну и остается вам задать окну `DataContext` и привязать в XAML все это дело.

Comment: Вот как раз, исследую шо такое Binding , спасибо!